# MySQL query will not return return value or give error message. (Query optimization)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

As a homework assignment I've been given three different datadumps of reddit posts that I'm supposed to write a bunch of queries for. The size of the datadumps are 12mb, 1gb and 2.5gb compressed. I started out with the smallest dataset and wrote queries for them which worked fine, however when I run the queries on the larger datasets they take alot of time to execute. Most of them works but one of the queries takes so long time that it cant even execute.

The Query is supposed to get the Users which has the most/least total of post scores(sum of users post score).

```
(SELECT `post_author` AS AUTHOR, SUM(`post_score`) AS SCORE FROM `post` GROUP BY `post_author` ORDER BY `SCORE` ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT `post_author` AS AUTHOR, SUM(`post_score`) AS SCORE FROM `post` GROUP BY `post_author` ORDER BY `SCORE` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

I'm using EasyPHP to host a phpMyAdmin db.

Now I'm not sure if this is a memoryproblem or a timeproblem. I tried raising 'ExecTimeLimit' in the phpMyAdmin config but that didn't seem to make a difference. Also I would appreciate any tips on what I can look into to make the query more efficient.

Create SQL:

```
Create SQL: SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `post_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_body` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_link` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_created` date NOT NULL,
  `post_author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `post_sub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_score` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: This is not enough to help you. Post create table for post table and the explain for your query. However, pls be aware that a mysql server on a laptop may be inadequate running such long queries and phpmyadmin is also not the most suitable application for running long queries!

Comment: Have you added an index on post_author on the post table you have created?

Comment: You table(s) are a fair size and have no indexes. Adding an index on post_author will likely help greatly.